# React - component for every styled element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm learning React.

It seems React highly promotes composition. **Create React App** even advises against reuse of css class.

Let's say I have a container, which is a white box, with nice rounded corner and shadow, etc. It can contain anything. That's it. No logic. Not much html except a `<div>`

Traditionally, I would just create a global css class named `.white-box` and then apply it to any `<div>` that I want it to be this white box.

I know in React you can do this, too. You can do whatever you want. But what is the general practice? From what I found online, it seems I should create a component for it and put any children inside:

`<WhiteBox>
    <div>anything</div>
</WhiteBox>`

Isn't it overkill? What are the benefits of doing this? Should I create a component for everything that can be re-used, even when it is such a small thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is honestly a matter of personal preference and experience.

For example, the seemingly pragmatic way would be to use a `.white-box` class on a div; *it's super easy and requires no imports!*

A bit later down the line, you decide that every white box inside some other control needs *a bit more shadow*, so you go and add a CSS rule for `.some-component .white-box`, and bam, now you got a shadow'ier white box without messing with the original CSS class. *Nice and easy!*

**The problem** with that is that when you do it once or twice, it's fine. But you'll soon develop a habit for "patching" the class name rules for specific purposes, and before you know it you're mixing rules without knowing it yourself, which is exactly what it says on the tin: **Cascading** Style Sheets.

I've been there myself, and it's no fun to maintain. Now I create components for everything, even things as simple as a white box. The trick is to name them right; you wouldn't call it `WhiteBox` because if you change the color of the box down the line, the rest of your code is a lie. ;) Instead, call it something like `ContentBox`; something that describes it's **purpose**, not *what it looks like*. Then use props to determine what characteristics the box should have:

```
<ContentBox shadow padded rounded>Awesome</ContentBox>
```

I'm personally a big fan of [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) because they make sure that class rules never clash which avoids the issue outlined above entirely. Instead, if you want a class to inherit some styles from another, CSS Modules lets you compose them together.

Example CSS modules file:

```
.root {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

And a React component:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './ContentBox.css'

export default function ContentBox({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>{children}</div>
  )
}
```

The actual classname being used is actually something like `ContentBox__root_abcd123random` so even if you have another CSS file with the same `.root` class, the rules never clash.

---

An added bonus of doing it this way is that your components are now portable to other projects because it only depends on styling within the CSS file that ships with the component. I've enjoyed great reuse using this strategy across many internal web apps at our company.

Comment: Great answer/advice/example!

Answer (score 2):

That's right. It's not overkill when you are confident that features will be the same across your app. For example, you can have the nice shadow styles as you said, or guarantee that all containers have white background or might have a `fluid` prop which will expand the element for the whole parent width.

In fact, there are React frameworks like `Semantic UI React` that do [exactly like this](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/container).

Every time you see yourself designing some HTML that should be consistent in your codebase, that should ring a bell for creating a single unique component for it. And if you think your components are big enough, maybe you should break them down.

This approach makes your code easy to test, once it's way more easier to test small stuff with limited and well-defined functionalities than a big component which several features. Once you glue them together, because of React [one-way data flow approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519889/can-anyone-explain-the-difference-between-reacts-one-way-data-binding-and-angula), you know exactly why stuff is not working - you now have simple components for each feature, and if they are not working as expected, there is only one flow where data might have came.

As a beginner those concepts might be hard to grasp. But once you start digging into large codebases and projects, you will see how "modularizing" your application will have long-term benefits.

Comment: But those `Semantic UI Components` display data in some sort of way and take defined props (whether its a user card or an input field), if its just for html, the class is perfectly reusable imho

Comment: Not necessarily. They can be just pure CSS to adjust elements. Some more sophisticated, but still only CSS.